# HTTPS React app inside intranet still shows as untrusted

Tags: node.js, reactjs, https

We have a Node.js application with React frontend for warehouse management. One of the features of the app is a real-time QR code reader (Which requires webcam access that is only available if the website is running under a secured connection).

This application is accessible only inside the intranet network (eg.: 192.168.157.12:80) and has no domain. I know after some research that the way is to obtain a self-signed certificate and I already did that successfully.
The problem is that it shows on the client-side as an "untrusted" certificate and require the user to confirm/bypass a bunch of warning to access the app - this is a no-go for us because a lot of the users are not tech-savvy and it presents a significant issue.

Is there any way to show the self-signed certificate as fully valid inside the local network on Windows PC and Android tablet with chrome browser and not bother the user with any warnings and alerts?
If not, can you please suggest any other method how to handle this?

Thank You.